# Adding multiple 'Tags' for an image in windows explorer using python script

Tags: python, windows, exif, exiftool

Windows explorer has an option to add tags to image through image properties > Details > Tags [Image properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdG6U.png).
Can I modify this using python or any other automated method (bash)?
I tried using exif library
`pip install exif` 
But it only allows to change image title/subject through its ImageDescription attribute [exif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dp5V.png).
Further, exiftools library has an attributes XPkeywords, is it relevant for updating tags? What does it update?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows "Tags" property reads data from three different sources in the file, if they exist.  They are the `EXIF:XPKeywords`, the `IPTC:Keywords`, and the `XMP:Subject` tags.  The first appears in the EXIF block, but is not part of the EXIF standard.  For the most part, it's a Windows only tag that isn't read by most software.

The other two tags are part of the older IPTC IIM/Legacy standard and the newer XMP standard.  These would be the tags you want to write to if you want future compatibility.

On the command line, [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) and [Exiv2](https://exiv2.org/) are common tools for writing metadata into image files.  They both have wrappers that will help write data using them. See [PyExifTool](https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/) and [python-exiv2](https://pypi.org/project/python-exiv2/).  There may be other libraries that can use but you want to make sure they can write IPTC and/or XMP data.

I believe that the EXIF library you installed only writes EXIF data, not other types of data.